# How can I get table data by replacing a column value with &

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data from table and replace my requirement but it showing wrong.

```
SELECT t.*, REPLACE(m, ',', '') FROM mytable t;
```

by this am getting as whole data and separate m column with replacement

I have data

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM FRAUD;
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
| ALERT_ID | INSERTION_TIME | EVENT_ID | SRC_ADDR      | SRC_USER | SEQ_NUM | CREATED_TIME        | MESSAGE                                                                                                           | DEVICE_TAG | TYPE  | NW_GROUP      | VARIABLE1 | VARIABLE2 |
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
|        1 | 1613363639767  |  5010009 | 192.168.3.199 | n/a      |      12 | 2021-02-14 23:52:37 | Received more than 1200 "180 Ringing" responses in last 30 seconds, exceeds the limit of 1200 as defined by rule. |            | Alert | 1613363639767 | NULL      | NULL      |
|        1 | 1613395100854  |  5010009 | 192.168.3.199 | n/a      |      12 | 2021-02-15 05:18:20 | Received more than 1200 "180 Ringing" responses in last 30 seconds, exceeds the limit of 1200 as defined by rule. |            | Alert | Unknown       | NULL      | NULL      |
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want data as

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM FRAUD;
| ALERT_ID | INSERTION_TIME | EVENT_ID | SRC_ADDR      | SRC_USER | SEQ_NUM | CREATED_TIME        | MESSAGE                                                                                                           | DEVICE_TAG | TYPE  | NW_GROUP      | VARIABLE1 | VARIABLE2 |
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
|        1 | 1613363639767  |  5010009 | 192.168.3.199 | n/a      |      12 | 2021-02-14 23:52:37 | Received more than 1200 "180 Ringing" responses in last 30 seconds& exceeds the limit of 1200 as defined by rule. |            | Alert | 1613363639767 | NULL      | NULL      |
|        1 | 1613395100854  |  5010009 | 192.168.3.199 | n/a      |      12 | 2021-02-15 05:18:20 | Received more than 1200 "180 Ringing" responses in last 30 seconds& exceeds the limit of 1200 as defined by rule. |            | Alert | Unknown       | NULL      | NULL      |
```

But i am getting with my query

```
mysql> SELECT *,REPLACE(MESSAGE,',','&') FROM FRAUD;
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ALERT_ID | INSERTION_TIME | EVENT_ID | SRC_ADDR      | SRC_USER | SEQ_NUM | CREATED_TIME        | MESSAGE                                                                                                           | DEVICE_TAG | TYPE  | NW_GROUP      | VARIABLE1 | VARIABLE2 | REPLACE(MESSAGE,',','&')                                                                                          |
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 1613363639767  |  5010009 | 192.168.3.199 | n/a      |      12 | 2021-02-14 23:52:37 | Received more than 1200 "180 Ringing" responses in last 30 seconds, exceeds the limit of 1200 as defined by rule. |            | Alert | 1613363639767 | NULL      | NULL      | Received more than 1200 "180 Ringing" responses in last 30 seconds& exceeds the limit of 1200 as defined by rule. |
|        1 | 1613395100854  |  5010009 | 192.168.3.199 | n/a      |      12 | 2021-02-15 05:18:20 | Received more than 1200 "180 Ringing" responses in last 30 seconds, exceeds the limit of 1200 as defined by rule. |            | Alert | Unknown       | NULL      | NULL      | Received more than 1200 "180 Ringing" responses in last 30 seconds& exceeds the limit of 1200 as defined by rule. |
+----------+----------------+----------+---------------+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please show us the INPUTS and then describe what you want as OUTPUT

Comment: If you dont want the `m` column as part of the `t.*` then you have to specify all the columns by name that you want from the query

Comment: @RiggsFolly i updated quetion i am trying to get data by java code

Comment: After your update - see comment 2 and maybe add an alias `REPLACE(MESSAGE,',','&') as MESSAGE`

Comment: how can i need to write in java

Comment: REPLACE(MESSAGE,',','&') as MESSAGE  by this just adding extra filed and getting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want the MESSAGE column duplicated, you have to mention all the columns by name rather than using `*`

Also an Alias will make getting at the value for the replaced MESSAGE column easier

```
SELECT ALERT_ID, INSERTION_TIME, EVENT_ID, SRC_ADDR, SRC_USER,
        SEQ_NUM, CREATED_TIME, 
        REPLACE(MESSAGE,',','&') as MESSAGE, 
        DEVICE_TAG, TYPE,NW_GROUP, VARIABLE1, VARIABLE2
```